# useDispatch won't recognize action from typescript file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm using typescript in my react project and I'm trying to dispatch this function:

```
import { register } from "../../actions/auth";
```

auth is a typescript file

```
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 dispatch(register(registrationData));
```

when Im trying to dispatch the action I get this error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\Desktop\client\src\actions\auth.js'
```

the file itself is TS, but its looking for js by default, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you just add the extension to the import statement? `import { register } from "../../actions/auth.ts"`

Comment: This is an issue with your environment.  Is there anything weird in your `tsconfig` include or exclude? https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Project_Files_0 https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html Or in your webpack extensions? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/  Please post all of your configuration files.

Comment: Most likely error: missing ".ts" in Webpack extensions settings: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions